# how to get all data according to key word in redis

Tags: redis

I want to get All data stored "hiNID" in cluster of redis

1. "hiNID_41"
2. "inven_584949191000001_1"
3. "goods_single_584990171000001_1"
4. "hiNID_41"
5. "inve_585008361000001_1"
6. "hiNID_417"
7. "goods_585009981000001"

Comment: Where do you run the Redis Cluster? Are you running a hosted Redis?

Comment: @GuyKorland yes i'm using redis cluster

Comment: hosted or self-managed?